# calling a function method using [ ] in javascript instead of . operator

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have something like this

```
var foo = {};
foo.name = "Hello";
foo.someMethod= function(){
   console.log("SomeMethod called");
}

console.log("Use [ ] operator : " + foo["name"]);
console.log("Use dot notation : " + foo.name);

foo.someMethod();  //This works.
foo[someMethod](); //Why does this not work
```

My question is why does the last statement not work ? Can method not be called through [ ] the operators ?

Comment: You have quotes in `foo["name"]` but not in `foo[someMethod]`, why?

Comment: When using square brackets, the bit in the brackets is an expression, so it is evaluated and *someMethod* is treated as an identifier. So the script engine goes looking for a *someMethod* variable to get its value and can't find it.

Comment: `foo[someMethod]()` doesn't work for the same reason that `foo[name]` doesn't work.

Comment: And you fix it exactly the same way. Why do you think it works differently if the property contains a function than if it contains a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need quotes around `someMethod`

`foo['someMethod']();` will work.

Answer (score 3):

Because `someMethod` will be interpreted as a identifier. There is no identifier called `someMethod` in the scope. If you examine the console output you will see a telling error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: someMethod is not defined

You have to use it like this `foo["someMethod"]();`